# Symmetrical Component Analysis Circulating Current & KVL

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

I was reading in John Grainger Power System Analysis and have a question in mind. Below is the delta connection of an unbalaced 3 phase system with unsymmetrical loads $$Z_{\Delta 1} \neq Z_{\Delta 2} \neq Z_{\Delta 3}$$

[image]

So my questions are :

1) Can we use "super-position" of the different components and draw such circuit for each component alone?

[image]

2) If so then wouldn't that mean that we can write kvl on the delta loop 
$$Z_{\Delta 1} I_{ab}^0 + Z_{\Delta 2} I_{ab}^0 +Z_{\Delta 3} I_{ab}^0 =0$$ however the book clearly says that we could have circulating current in the loop which is non-zero but that violates the KVL equation I've written above. This lead me to conclude that probably drawing such circuits is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use superposition on this linear circuit.  KVL will hold.  From your terminology I'm guessing you are talking about symmetrical components.  For this delta connected load their will be positive and negative sequence current flowing from the sources.  No zero sequence will flow because there is no path for it.  A delta connected load does not connect to the zero sequence neutral bus (in symmet analysis), whereas it does connect to the positive seq neutral bus and negative seq neutral bus.

The terminology circulating current makes no sense to me here.  There is not some mysterious current circulating.  There can't be unless you add a source inside the delta.  Circulating current has meaning if you are talking about the delta winding of a transformer that also has a grounded wye winding.  In that case current can circulate in the delta due to transformer effect while zero sequence flows in the wye winding.